# How to output radio buttons variable to frontend - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, radio-button, wordpress-theming

I am working on my themes options panel (in administration/backend) and I am struggling with **radio buttons**.
 
I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/cferdinandi/wp-theme-options/ for creating radio buttons. They are now in themes options but I don't know how to make output of it into themes frontend. 
I want just to try to `echo` the value of radio buttons form but I don't know the name of the variable in which it is saved.
Normally in php I would do it like so: `if ($_POST['NAME']=="VALUE1") { echo "Some text here"; }`
With text fields I use just it: `<?php echo $options['csscolor_setting']; ?>` (in for example header.php)
And in functions.php i have:

```
function csscolor_setting() {

    $options = get_option('theme_options');  echo "<input name='theme_options[csscolor_setting]' type='text' value='{$options['csscolor_setting']}' />";

}
```

But it's not possible with radio buttons. For now it would be enough if I know how to make some code like this real:

```
<?php if ($some_variable == 'yes')
{echo 'Something';}
?>
```

Or just `<?php echo $some_variable; ?>`
But this $some_variable I can't find in my code.

**Here is my code in functions.php regarding to radio buttons.**

```
add_settings_field( 'sample_radio_buttons', __( 'Allow triangles in background?', 'YourTheme' ), 'YourTheme_settings_field_sample_radio_buttons', 'theme_options', 'general' );
```

*Creating options for radio buttons field*

```
function YourTheme_sample_radio_button_choices() {

    $sample_radio_buttons = array(

        'yes' => array(

            'value' => 'yes',

            'label' => 'Yes'

        ),

        'no' => array(

            'value' => 'no',

            'label' => 'No'

        ),

    );

    return apply_filters( 'YourTheme_sample_radio_button_choices', $sample_radio_buttons );

}
```

*Creating sample radio buttons field*

```
function YourTheme_settings_field_sample_radio_buttons() {

    $options = YourTheme_get_theme_options();

    foreach ( YourTheme_sample_radio_button_choices() as $button ) {

    ?>

    <div class="layout">

        <label class="description">

            <input type="radio" name="YourTheme_theme_options[sample_radio_buttons]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $button['value'] ); ?>" <?php checked( $options['sample_radio_buttons'], $button['value'] ); ?> />

            <?php echo $button['label']; ?>

        </label>

    </div>

    <?php

    }

}
```

*Getting the current options from the database and setting deafaults.*

```
function YourTheme_get_theme_options() {

        $saved = (array) get_option( 'YourTheme_theme_options' );

        $defaults = array(

            'sample_checkbox'       => 'off',

            'sample_text_input'     => '',

            'sample_select_options' => '',

            'sample_radio_buttons'  => 'yes',

            'sample_textarea'       => '',

        );

        $defaults = apply_filters( 'YourTheme_default_theme_options', $defaults );

        $options = wp_parse_args( $saved, $defaults );

        $options = array_intersect_key( $options, $defaults );

        return $options;

    }
```

Then there is a little bit more code about sanitization and validation but I think it should not have any inffluence on variable in form.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wordpress runs on PHP, but is not itself PHP.  It's wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the frontend you can just use the same function as the one you're using in your get_theme_options function, namely:

```
get_option( 'YourTheme_theme_options' );
```

Have a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Actually I needed also to add little more code to `echo` the value of checked radio button. 
 
My code in frontend (for example footer.php) looks like this:

```
<?php $YourTheme_theme_options = get_option('YourTheme_theme_options');
echo $YourTheme_theme_options['sample_radio_buttons']; ?>
```

I hope this will help somebody with developing of theme options page.